# ZK element 'template' not allowed in listbox

Tags: mvvm, intellij-idea, zk

I'm using IntelliJ to develop Zk rendered pages and currently attempting to use MVVM to put data into a ListBox.

However I keep getting my *template* tags highlighted with the message from IntelliJ *Element template not allowed here*.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong from the below code?

```xml
<?page title="Main" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul"
             xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul
                                   http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul/zul.xsd">

 ...

           <center>
                <listbox model="@bind(cvm.contractsList)">
                    <listhead>
                        <listheader label="Contract #" hflex="1" />
                        <listheader label="Contract Name" hflex="1" />
                    </listhead>
                    <!-- below tags are red -->
                    <template name="model" var="contract">
                        <listitem>
                            <listcell label="@bind(contract.contractNumber)" />
                            <listcell label="@bind(contract.contractName)" />
                        </listitem>
                    </template>
```

My ZK dependencies from Maven are as follows:

```
...

<properties>
    <zk.version>6.5.2</zk.version>
</properties>

...

<dependencies>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
      <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
      <version>${zk.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
      <artifactId>zhtml</artifactId>
      <version>${zk.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
      <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
      <version>${zk.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
      <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
      <version>${zk.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

On what might be related - my VM is returning values, but my listBox is not currently displaying them (but I have not yet tested the code since changing config from `@load` to `@bind`).

Any help on the syntax issue would be appreciated.

**Addendum - Another example**:
It must be something in my schema configuration in IntelliJ. I always need to have the namespace at the top of my zul files but I notice that so many of the examples do not add this. I don't know why that is.

I have another example of invalidating a valid syntax. Today I had trouble with the `validationMessages` tag which is indicated as an error by IntelliJ. Sample code for that:

```
<window id="contractsReport" border="none" width="100%"     
      apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') 
      @init('com.t2.anomalies.vm.AnomaliesReportsVm')" 
      validationMessages="@id('vmsgs')">
```

Comment: changing from `@load` to `@bind` will not do anything(bind is load + save), when you run this in a local server, do you get a fault or not?

Comment: @chillworld Yeah I see what you mean. I got it working by fixing up the NotifyChange annotation. The syntax highlighting errors I think must have something to do with the IntelliJ + workspace + Zk combination.... as I was explaining to a peer today, it works but it's poor because it equates to a False Positive in my IDE

Comment: Bug in IDE? You imported the namespace so that is weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong. It's just the `zul.xsd` schema is not very well maintained by the ZK folks. ...some other things are missing, too. So we'll just have to live with that. It actually is working at run time. So it's just some development time discomfort.

Anyway I used to put `<zk> </zk>` around `<template>` so the editor will accept it. But I stopped doing that for some reason I can't remember :-/ ...